# Ajax / jquery later versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm a bit out of my depth here and need some help. The following works fine with jquery 1.7 and below, but will not work with later versions. Can someone please steer me in the right direction?

```
  // -- Start AJAX Call --
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "do-login.php", // Send the login info to this page
     data: str,
     success: function (msg) {
        $("#status").ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {

           // Show 'Submit' Button
           $('#submit').show();

           // Hide Gif Spinning Rotator
           $('#ajax_loading').hide();

           if (msg == 'OK') {// LOGIN OK?
                    go_to_private_page();
           } else { // ERROR?
              var login_response = msg;
              $('#login_response').html(login_response);
           }
        });
     }
  });
  // -- End AJAX Call --
```

Comment: Why would you put a global ajax event handler inside the success callback.

Comment: As I said I'm a bit out of my depth here and I don't follow your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "do-login.php", // Send the login info to this page
     data: str
  }).done(function (msg) {
       // Do your thing here.
  });
```

Take a look at JQuery document: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion. However the result that his gives is a "success" message box with js 1.7 and the same problem with later versions of js.